# Flink: Left join equivalent of Dataset API in Batch mode of DataStream API?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-batch

It has been mentioned in Flink docs that [DataSet API will be deprecated](https://flink.apache.org/roadmap.html#deep-batch--streaming-unification-for-the-datastream-api) in future. So I am looking into prototyping this **Dataset API** to **DataStream API in [Batch Mode](https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/12/10/release-1.12.0.html#batch-execution-mode-in-the-datastream-api)** (which I believe is in Beta right now) migration.

We have this(similar) code in our codebase that uses *leftOuterJoin* on a DataSet.

```
 DataSet<SomeOutType> joined_out =  datasetA.
                leftOuterJoin(datasetB, JoinOperatorBase.JoinHint.BROADCAST_HASH_SECOND)
                .where((left) -> coalesce(left.getId(), -9999999L))
                .equalTo((right) -> right.company_id).with((JoinFunction<SomeTypeA, SomeTypeB, SomeOutType>) (left, right) -> {
                    SomeOutType recNew = SomeOutType.newBuilder().build();
                    recNew.setCustomerId(left.getCustomerId());
                    recNew.setCustomerName((right != null && right.cust_name != null) ? right.cust_name : "Blank");
                    ....
                    ....
                    ....
                    return  recNew;

                });
```

The problem is I'm not able to find *Left Join* or *Left Outer Join* equivalent in the Datastream API docs - [Join](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/joining/).

Since they are thinking of totally deprecating the DataSet API, I am assuming there should be a way to do this Left Outer Join in DataStream API now.

Can someone please guide me in the right way to do this?
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relational operations on DataSets (e.g., joins) are being deprecated in favor of using the relational operations offered by the Table/SQL API, which is fully interoperable with the DataStream API.

See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/tableapi/#joins and https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/.

You can either use Table connectors and perform a join directly on the tables they produce, or convert datastreams to tables before performing the join. And you can convert from tables back to datastreams if needed for further processing. Given the table/stream duality, these "conversions" don't really cost anything. See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/data_stream_api/.

FWIW, Flink 1.14 was just released, and it includes a number of improvements related to this topic. In particular, only in 1.14 (and beyond) can you combine the Table API with the DataStream API in batch execution mode.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for the reply, I'll look into the Table API, too. 

Since yesterday, after the question here, I did some searching and found [Process Function](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/datastream/operators/process_function/#low-level-joins) section. Do you think something like a left join can also be emulated using this?

Comment: You certainly can implement a left join as a KeyedCoProcessFunction, but it’ll be more work.

Comment: Thanks David for your help!